# Is a transformation matrix with a homogeneous coordinates and a zero row surjective (onto)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Given the transformation matrix A, is it considered onto?

$A = \left( \begin{smallmatrix} 0&0&0\\ 5&-2&1\\ 0&0&1 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$

The definition of Onto: T:$R^n$→$R^m$ is said to be onto if each b in is the image of at least one x in $R^n$

Also, it is said that a transformation matrix is onto if the rank (dimension of the column space) is equal to m.

Since the transformation matrix has homogenous coordinates it, essentially will always map from $R^2$. However, I am not sure if it maps to a line in $R^2$ or simply $R^1$. It is obvious that the rank of the column space, ignoring the row added by the homogenous coordinates, is 1. So I'm not sure if m is 1 or 2 in this case.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: It maps $\mathbb R^3$ into $\mathbb R^3$. What can you say about the vector in the column space?

Comment: Spans \mathbb R^2 and thus does not span M? Thus is not onto? I would really love to get confirmation.

Comment: $\mathbb R^2$ isn't a subset of  $\mathbb R^3$. As for your question, every vector in the column space has $0$ as first component. Thus, the column space has dimension $\le 3-1=2$.